# "All Sites" has wrong information for the Japanese SO

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, localization

Currently, on the Stack Exchange ["All Sites" page](https://stackexchange.com/sites), the row for スタック・オーバーフロー (Stack Overflow in Japanese) has two obviously-wrong values:

- visits/day: 0
- site age: 2013y11m

If the latter is used somehow as the denominator in calculating the former, that would explain how these are caused by a single bug.

Comment: you should post your explanation of the bug as an answer to the duplicate question!